# Do two clients have to be subscribe to each other's presence in order to exchange messages in XMPP?

Tags: xmpp

I have read the following doc but somewhat confused between message sending, sending presence and subscription. 
https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0162.html#intro

Specifically, do two users have to subscribe to each other's presence to exchange messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

Presence subscription (usually) is just a way to control which entities can see your presence status. The exchange of message stanzas is not affected but the subscription status (if techniques like "Privacy Lists" are not used).